# Executing dynamically passed function call with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function call passed as a string:

```
var dcall = "tumbsNav(1)";
```

Is it possible to execute this dynamically like exec in SQL??

```
exec(dcall)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wherever you're storing

```
var dcall = "tumbsNav(1)";
```

You can instead store

```
var dcall = function() {
   return tumbsNav(1);
};
```

Wherever you were calling it, instead of calling

```
eval(dcall);
```

You can instead call

```
dcall();
```

<strike>The only case this wouldn't work is if `tumbsNav` wasn't defined at the time `var func = ...` is called. Then you would have to store the string. If the string is completely under your control, then there's no security hole, but be aware of all the problems mentioned by @Porco</strike>

As Kolink mentioned, my example would not cause a problem if `tumbsNav` was not defined when assigning it with a wrapped anonymous function that calls tumbs. The comment above would only make sense if the example had been the following:

```
var dcall = tumbsNav, darg = 1;
// later in the code, you can call
dcall(darg) ;
```

Comment: Actually you're wrong about it not working if `tumbsNav` is undefined when the function is created. It takes whatever value `tumbsNav` has when it's called, rergardless of what it was before. This is the subject of a lot of closure trip-ups.

Comment: @Kolink oops, what you said is 100% true, the anonymous function content is not evaluated until the function is called. I initially wrote this answer assigning `var dcall = tumbsNav,darg = 1`, `and calling dcall(darg)` In that case, my comment would be accurate.

Answer (score 3):

`eval` is the equivalent, but you should NOT use it.

Instead, pass the function like this:

```
var dcall = function() {tumbsNav(1);};
```

Then call it with:

```
dcall();
```

Comment: @RegisteredUser. Why use `eval` is a better question, in fact I would have upvoted my comment if I could... `:-)`

Comment: eval starts a compiler. There is often a much more efficient way to solve most problems without using eval. Check out this article for a good description of why not to use eval and **some** reasons where you should use it. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx

Comment: My answer mentions one case where you would need `eval`. if `tumbsNav` is not defined when you're assigning it to `dcall`; Not a very common scenario, but still a valid one.

Answer (score 3):

To do this, you want `eval(dcall)`.

**`eval` can open [terribly security holes and performance issues](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx) in your program**.  If you need to use it, that usually means you have designed your program poorly.

Instead, you might keep a reference to the function you  want to call and hold an array of arguments and use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), e.g., `tumbsNav.apply(null, [1]);`.  I don't know your code, so that's most general solution I can offer.

Comment: more simply (since you know the number of arguments), you would call `tumbsNav(1)`

Comment: True, but I want to keep it as general as possible, in case the OP needs to use this pattern elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Use eval(dcall).

As others have mentioned eval is considered bad practice. The main reasons for this are

1) Improper use can leave your code vulnerable to injection attacks.

2) Maintaining code becomes more difficult (no line numbers, can't use debugging tools)

3) Executes more slowly (browsers can't compile)

4) <strike>Scope becomes impossible to predict.</strike>

However, if you understand all these then eval can be very helpful.

Comment: The only item I disagree with is that scope is not impossible to predict. It runs in the scope where eval is run from.

Comment: It can be unpredictible, as seen here: http://blog.rakeshpai.me/2008/10/understanding-eval-scope-spoiler-its.html

Comment: Sorry Porco, but the behavior on that page is just as I expected. The scope of the eval is within a function, there's no reason it should change the global variable. Writing `eval("var foo=456")` within that function is the exact same effect as writing `var foo=456` within that function. The only unreliable cases are if you call `window.eval()` or if you pass a second parameter to `eval("code", scope)` (it's deprecated btw) https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval To sum it up, it's only unreliable if you use it in a way that is non-standard

Comment: Here's the link that says the window.eval is also deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/eval

Comment: Thanks for the links, you've changed my mind. I'd considered removing it but I like the striking out idea much better :)